# File is getting saved in Documents folder instead of Desktop when tried using autoit in selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver, autoit

I am trying to save the downloaded file in Desktop but the file is getting saved in  Documents folder below is AutoIt code and i am calling this in selenium webdriver. Can anyone help me out to save file in Desktop.

```
Sleep(1500)
ControlSetText("Save As", "", "Edit1", @DesktopDir & "\test.pdf")
Sleep(1000)
ControlClick("Save As", "", "Button2")
```

Comment: `Edit1` accepts an existing path with a filename (Windows 7, Firefox 56). `Button1` is "Save" and `Button2` is "Cancel" button. Other than improving the code with WinWait() etc. and changing `Button2` to `Button1`, it does save to the Desktop.

Comment: @michael_heath, Changed Button2 to Button1 and still its not working. Before it used to save in Documents after changes now saving in Documents folder as well.

Comment: Window Info Tool will tell if `Button2` is correct or not. I only state settings for my environment.

Comment: Does manually typing full file path into the edit control work? Does it save with the filename you specified and only ignores the path? Try saving to any path without spaces or non-english letters, does that work? Does your username contain hieroglyphics (i.e. Chinese) or  left-to-right text (such as Arabic)?